# JMeter ForEach controller with list of Objects not being iterated over

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223, jmeter-5.0

Following is my test plan. Where ForEach controller should loop through all the task Ids stored in user defined variable "userTaskIds". I tried defining list with 
both `def myList = []  and List<Object> listId = new ArrayList<Object>();`. In both the case its failed to loop.
[image]
ForEach controller not looping with "userTaskIds" variable. Here i tried with/without "add "_" before number ?"

[image]

Following are debug sampler result and Log view panel
[image]

Log View

[image]

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? I just updated it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) expects this:

- userTaskIds_1
- userTaskIds_2
- ...

And

- userTaskIds_matchNr = number of occurences

So in your JSR223 script you need to do this in each loop iteration :

Replace responseJSON.each by

```
  responseJSON.eachWithIndex {
     it, iterationLoop ->
```

Then

> vars.put("userTaskIds_"+(iterationLoop+1), ""+it.id)

**where iterationLoop must start with 1 and be incremented.**

and after loop:

> vars.put("userTaskIds_matchNr", Integer.toString(myList.size()));

Comment: Worked like a charm !!! but still not able to understand completely. Any links/blogs to understand properly mainly jsr223 + groovy ??

Comment: Read the ref doc I linked to and search for iterateWithIndex in groovy